# JavaScript No Longer Working after adding to External File

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I need to migrate my javascript from inside my .aspx page and into a external .js file.  In doing such in my .aspx file I have added

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

And JavaScript.js is the name of the external file I added.  This is my JavaScript that I have added to the .js file that is now not working in an external file.

```
var limit = 2;
$(function () {
    $('#form1').on('change', '[id*="cbxAnswers"]', function (evt) {
        if ($('[id*="cbxAnswers"]:checked').length > limit) {
            this.checked = false;
            alert('Max number to pick is ' + limit);
        }
    });
});
```

And for clarification - the .aspx has a form called form1 and also has a checkboxlist called cbxAnswers.

What needs to be altered so that the syntax works in the external .js file as well?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the dev tools console? Is the casing of your filename correct? Is the file path to your script file correct?

Comment: @jeff - dev console shows error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at JavaScript.js:2

Comment: You need to add `jQuery`

Comment: You have to load jQuery BEFORE your external file.

Comment: @jeff - that remedied.  Why does the jquery references have to be made before the reference to the external file?

Comment: Because your external file needs jQuery?  How does it use jQuery if it isn't loaded?

Comment: FYI you included two jQuery scripts, you want only 1.

Comment: Why are you loading two different versions of jQuery?

Comment: and why are you loading one over http vs https?

Comment: @JLRishe - I did not realize I only needed one.  I will remove the other